# LINQ - Cannot implicity convert type, An explicit conversion exsist

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm using queries for the first time in C# and I'm having trouble with this simple one.

**Here is my controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string campus = Request.Params["Campus"];

    if (campus != null)
    {
        if (campus == "Alle")
        {
            return View(db.Teachers.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            var teachers = (from t in db.Teachers
                            where t.Campus == campus
                            select t);

            var Model = new ViewModel
            {
                Teachers = teachers.ToList(),
            };
            return View(Model);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View(db.Teachers.ToList());
    }           
}
```

and this is the model for for **ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

However, I can't get the Query to work, it always gives me a redline under

```
Teachers = teachers.ToList()
```

with the error

> Cannot implicity convert type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit
>   conversion exsist.

I'm pretty sure it's a very simple fix, but I've tried numerous things and I can't silve it right away.

Incase you need it, here is my **Teacher class**

```
public class Teacher
{
    [key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Campus { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Teachers` is an `IQueryable<Teacher>`, not a `List<Teacher>`, how do you expect `ToList()` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that this:

```
Teachers = teachers.ToList()
```

Tries to assign a `List<Teacher>` to an `IQueryable<Teacher>`.

I think you may want your `ViewModel` to hold the actual data, not the queries, as you're returning them right after the creation. This means that instead of using `IQueryable<T>`, which will hold the *deferred query*, you can store the actual result of the query by using a `List<Teacher>` or `IList<Teacher>`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IList<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public IList<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

And now the `Enumerable.ToList` invocation will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `Teachers` object is an IQueryable of `Teacher` and you try to assign a list to it, which can't be done since List is not implementing that interface. Why do you need to `.ToList()` them anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I want to print them out on a view

Comment: And you can't use them as IQueryable because..? :P

Comment: Well, tbh I'm very new to this and this is how we got taught at school, so I figured I used that method :D